# Using boost.asio on esp32 (lwip)

Tags: boost, boost-asio, freertos, lwip, esp32

I am trying to port code using `boost.asio` onto the esp32 (esp-idf) which in turn uses lwip, mbedtls and FreeRTOS using preemptive multitasking.

The esp-idf exposes a Linux/Posix-like interface and most stuff compiles out of the box. Lwip exposes a standard BSD socket interface including select() and blocking and non-blocking sockets etc, but it does not have poll().

So in principle I would think that everything should be there to make boost.asio happy. What I find is that boost.asio (e.g. socket_ops.ipp) contains code variants for many OSes, and it is clear to me that esp32 is not a supported platform.

My question is: What is currently the best alignment of the BOOST_ASIO_* #defines when targeting the esp32?

(I am currently drilling into this and I am modifying both boost.asio and the esp-idf to fit together, but I already made unnecessary changes, thus asking this question.)

Comment: Having some experience with both, I don't think those are a really good match. E.g. the blocking mode of asio is thread-safe, you would typically run a separate thread which is blocked on receive. That's not possible with LWIP, since it's sockets are not thread-safe. Unless you want to build your own thread-safe wrapper on top of the raw API.

Comment: For nonblocking/event-driven mode you might find that LWIP misses some things that you typically want for an eventloop. E.g. there's no way to wakeup a select, e.g. through signalfd or a pipe.
Also even-driven programming is often heavy on dynamic allocations, since you e.g. might want to e.g. queue (io_service::post) a handler. Or to bind a function object as callback. But dynamic allocations are something that should be avoided on these restricted platforms.

Comment: @Matthias247: I fully agree with your comments. I wouldn't ever suggest for an ESP32 project to use boost. I have a very restricted single threaded use case, and I probably can fix all threading related problems. At the moment I am astonished how tight boost and the concrete openssl implementation are bound together. Nasty!

Comment: Newer development versions of LwIP have poll(), checkout the git master rather than stable releases. @Matthias247 the lack of signals or pipes can easily be worked around with a socket bound to the loopback address. Send it a message to cancel select